# What is the common way of dealing with libraries dependencies when building with compilers different from target distributions?

Tags: c++, linux

In case when let's say your project is built with one version of C++ compiler, and its potential target system provides shared libraries built with another version, how is this commonly approached? In particular it's a question about libstdc++.

When something is built within the same distribution (for example on Linux and etc.) it's rather straightforward - everything is built with the same compiler. But what about projects like Mozilla Firefox which ship a binary supposedly compatible with many potential targets? I know one way to do it is statically link C++ dependencies, which reduces ABI incompatibility issues and limits external linking just to a few C libraries, but when I look at actual Firefox binary (from the stock Mozilal build for Linux x86_64) I see this:

```
ldd firefox
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff561fc000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff868c9f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff868a9b000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff868892000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff868587000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff868286000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff86806f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff867cc6000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff868ee8000)
```

Here Firefox dynamically links with libstdc++. So how can it properly work across different versions of libstdc++ or it just assumes ABI compatibility and that's it?

Comment: Shared libraries should provide compiler independent ABI's.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: But sadly, [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) is probably compiler & [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific - even if most of them are common to all the compilers for a given system.

Comment: Well, in this case shared libstdc++.so.6 is clearly compiler dependent. So how does it work? For example, is it compatible between different versions of GCC?

Comment: C++ tends to work best when all the source code is avail to the compiler (as in the case of boost and other template libraries).  Shared C++ libraries are messy due to ABI incompatibilities etc.

Answer (score 0):

*The common way...*

- The designer / developer decides which (shared) libraries to use. Here, an option to link statically can be given (-> build configuration).
- The designer also chooses if and how to verify versions of the used libraries at the build time and/or install time and/or run time.
- The packager that creates binary package for a distinct target will usually compile the binary with the target's tool chain and libraries.
- If binary-only distribution is needed for different targets, then the packager needs to provide a way to check the environment and used libraries at the install time (-> installer). Either the installer or the application itself can check which tool chain was used to build a shared library and either proceed, abort with an error or issue a warning and offer to continue.
- The packager can provide a set of binary modules in the package and the installer program will choose the ones that are needed and are compatible with the given target and environment at install time.

It is of course *lege artis* and should be *the common way* to avoid any assuming -
and optionally leave it to the user to ignore any warnings and try their luck.